# EF: Populate string property on domain entity from referenced table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Very new to EF and DDD. I have a POCO domain entity `Person` with a `public string Name` property. I am building my mappings on top of an existing database system. In some contexts, the `Person` table has a `'name'` column, in other contexts the `Person` table has a `'name_id'` column which references a `PersonName` lookup table consisting of the id and the actual name.

Using the Fluent API in my data access layer, how should I map that Name property when it gets it's value from another table? Am I going about this all wrong? Note: I do not have any say in the database design.

(Other properties and columns omitted)

Entity

```
public class Person
{
     public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Context1:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Context2:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonName
(
    NameID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    NameID INT REFERENCES PersonName(NameID)
)
```

How do I handle this when I map the model in each DbContext?

Comment: Can you show us models/classes?

Comment: @Cameron that okay?

Comment: I'm lost in your use of the word "context". Are these tables in separate databases or schemas?

Comment: @Cameron different databases that serve different purposes, but have some shared understanding of what a Person is.

Comment: Look at these articles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Cameron, I'm asking more if there's a way to do this when the entity doesn't have a property referencing a second entity.  I'm curious if there is a way to map the property to a different table without making a PersonName entity and mapping that.